# Cant connect to my minecraft server, did port forward, set inbound outbound rules for TCP and UDP, forge 1.12.2

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I've recently tried making a forge 1.12.2 Minecraft server and I can't connect to it via my public IP. Localhost works but not public IP. I have port forwarded my server and also set inbound and outbound TCP/UDP rules for 25565(my mc port) on my firewall. How I setup my mc server:

1. Ran forge installer to install my mc server into a folder on my desktop
2. Ran the forge jar
3. Changed the eula to true
4. Ran the forge jar again
5. added my local IP to the server.properties file
6. added mods and made run.bat file to run with more ram
7. Set inbound and outbound rules for firewall for 25565 UDP and TCP
8. Port forwarded 25565
9. Ran server again

After that I still could not use my public IP to join my Minecraft server.
If someone could help that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you set your local IP in the `server.properties` file. Try removing that value altogether, it's recommended to leave it empty, as stated here:
https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Server.properties#server-ip

Comment: Sorry to hear that. If your on Windows, maybe check your Antivirus, they often intercept on stuff like this and also double-check you router settings if the port forwarding is still enabled

Comment: I double checked my settings and i don't have a antivirus on the computer I'm hosting on
I also just tried giving java se binary full access in the firewall but still did not work

Comment: Did you check your router settings? You do realize that you have to enable port-forwarding there too? They have guides on how to accomplish that here: portforward.com

Comment: also according to one of those open port checkers port 25565 is open

Comment: so idk what happening

Comment: Are you trying to connect from the machine the server is running on? If so, did you use the public IP or "localhost"? Most routers block loopback connections, which means you can't use your public IP to join your server, you will have to use localhost. Only people from outside your LAN will be able to use your public IP

Comment: I'm connecting on a different computer but on the same wifi, and I tried both, connecting to the machines local IP works on any computer on my wifi and when I try the public IP on the different device on the same wifi, the public IP is not working, I'm currently trying to ask one of my friends to try it?